# Unable to declare static variable inside of static method

Tags: java

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() { }
}

class Bar {
    static Foo foo = new Foo(); // This is legal...

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        static int a = 0; // ... But why this is not?
    }
}
```

Why can't we declare a static variable inside of a static function?

Comment: Why would doing so make sense? When talking about variables that are only in scope inside the body of the method it makes no sense to say that they are "class-level".

Comment: Because it's non-sensical and/or redundant at best.

Comment: @user3580294 i am looking to declare a variable ( this not actual code) inside a loop static so that its value never changes with next iteration.

Comment: So you want a variable that keeps its value across method invocations? That's not what `static` means in Java. I'm 99% sure there's another question about this though...

Comment: Java's static variables are different from those in C. The language just isn't made that way. To get the same effect, you need to make a class variable outside the static method.

Comment: @Bayant_Singh then just dont change its value

Comment: Static means that there is only one copy of the variable stored in the memory. Final means that the variable will never change.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard you got me ...but how i digest it that it is different as i have that concept in my mind please provide some reference.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197062/local-static-variables-and-java/) is at least one of the questions that deal with local static variables a la C

Comment: @OldSchool mark the correct answer, please!

Comment: Please mark the best answer

Answer (score 22):

You have to make the static `final static` or remove `static`.

In Java, static means that it's a variable/method of a class, it belongs to the whole class but not to one of its certain objects. This means that static keyword can be used only in a 'class scope'.

Generally, in C, you can have statically allocated locally scoped variables. Unfortunately this is not directly supported in Java. But you can achieve the same effect by using nested classes.

For example, the following is allowed but it is bad engineering, because the scope of x is much larger than it needs to be. Also there is a non-obvious dependency between two members (x and getNextValue).

```
static int x = 42;
public static int getNextValue() {
    return ++x;
}
```

One would really like to do the following, but it is not legal:

```
public static int getNextValue() {
    static int x = 42;             // not legal :-(
    return ++x;
}
```

However you could do this instead,

```
public static class getNext {
    static int x = 42; 
    public static int value() {
        return ++x;
    }
}
```

It is better engineering at the expense of some ugliness.

Comment: Just because Java doesn't allow it doesn't mean that `static` couldn't "have any sense inside methods."  Sure it could, e.g., `static int getNextCounter() { static int x = 0; return x++; }` could return increasing values, and you could be confident that no other method could modify that `x`, because it would only have scope to that method.    Just because something isn't included in the language doesn't meant there's no way it could make sense.

Comment: we dont need `static` in `public static class getNext`, right?

Comment: "better engineering at the expense of some ugliness" seems to be a common theme in Java, though "better engineering" is debatable.

Comment: What do you mean by "You have to make the static final static or remove static"? If you mean the field `foo`, it is possible  to make it final, but the question author didn't ask about this. If you mean the variable `a`, this is not true - a Java variable can be `final`, but not `static final` (or `static`).

Answer (score 16):

Other people have explained how to deal with this at the coding level. Allow me to explain the logical and philosophical reasons why static within a method makes no sense. You have to ask the question "How long do you want the variable to last?".

- normal member variables last as long as the instance they are part of;
- variables declared within a method last until the method is exited;
- static class variables last for the lifetime of the class (i.e. forever for most purposes)

So how long do you want your 'static within a method' variable to last? If it's until the end of the method, then you can just use it without static. If it's for the lifetime of the class, then you can declare it as a static member variable. What other options are there?

C++ allows statics within a method, but they end up behaving just like a static class variable, but with reduced scope. Even in C++ they are rarely used. They also end up being stored exactly like static member variables. The pattern is widely considered to be dangerous and confusing, because it mounts to having a method 'remember' the value of what looks like a local variable from one invocation to another - a value which would be changed if some other piece of code chooses to execute the method in between the two invocations.

The Java designers decided that the small amount of benefit wasn't worth the additional complexity of the language.

Comment: "If it's for the lifetime of the class, then you can declare it as a static member variable. What other options are there?"  But what you don't get here is the guarantee that some other method in the class doesn't modify it.  That's what a static variable in a method would give you (as you point out):  limited scope.  Limited scope makes it *easier* to reason about the behavior of a program.

Comment: Obviously, static variables inside methods will be subjected to same concurrency issues as the class static fields. So, even C/C++ users have to be mindful of that.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable as final, not as static.

Static means that there is one per class not one per instance of the class. Final means it can't be modified after creation. (Although note that making a reference final does not make the class it references immutable).

In other words if you have a

```
final String[] array = new String[3];
```

You can no longer change that variable, for example if you wanted to assign to it a new array with a different size you could not. However you can modify the contents of the array.

```
array[0] = "test";
```

Because this modifies the contents, not the array itself.

The same thing holds for any mutable objects.

Comment: but array[0] is also a reference to string "test",and we have reprogrammed it although the array is final,so thats why you have mentioned this line in ().

Comment: @Bayant_singh `final String[] array` means that it is the *reference* that is `final`, not the object it points to.

Comment: @Bayant_singh I think you are right, your wording is a little vague though. Think of it as a cupboard. By making the cupboard final you are building it into the wall. You can no longer move the cupboard but you can still put things into and take things out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow user to create static variable locally as in java static variable's scope is global(i.e. throughout the program ) so there is no point of creating static variable locally thus in order to avoid ambiguousness java doesn't allow user to create static variable locally. We only  can create static variable as global static variable .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your expectation was behaviour like a `static` local variable with an initializer in a C function, which is initialized only once, namely in the first call of the function, but not in subsequent calls.

Java `static` fields is similar to C `static` local variables in that static fields are initialized only once, namely when the class is loaded.

Regarding the other answers mentioning it, `final` has **nothing** to do with this!
`final` means that the value of a variable/field cannot be changed after it has been initialized.

The idiomatic solution in Java is not using `static` fields in the first place, except for constants and things like caches and registries.

Often, a better solution is to write a new class instead that holds the value you would wanted to keep in the "`static`" variable as a regular (non-static) field. You can initialize it in the field declaration or in the new class's constructor, and then do the computation you wanted to do in a (non-static) method.