# Why can't I write a static string?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

   public static void main(String []args){
       static String[] str={"one","two"};
       Date date =new Date();
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       String year = "2018";
       String month ="4";
       int day =10;

       cal.set(Integer.parseInt(year),Integer.parseInt(month),day);
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
       // etc.
    }
}
```

Error message :

> error: illegal start of expression
>
> static String[] str={"one","two"};

Comment: you can't use `static` in the method ! did you mean `final`

Comment: No, I didn't mean final...

Comment: A local variable only exist in the scope of the method itself. Having a `static` local variable would not be accessible from `HelloWorld.str` since this is not in the scope of the method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269308/why-cant-we-declare-static-variables-inside-a-function-body-even-when-the-functi    https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-I-declare-a-static-variable-inside-main-method-in-Java

Comment: The real answer here is: you do not understand what the *static* keyword is about.

Comment: Such use of `static` would be valid in C. It isn’t in Java. It’s a design decision. You may suggest that it be made possible in Java 12; I wouldn’t expect you to get anywhere with it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is invalid syntax. You don't apply the `static` modifier to local variables. Remove `static`.

If `str` is meant to be a class variable, then declare it outside the method:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    static String[] str={"one","two"};
```

*Static* is a concept for members of types (interfaces, classes, enums...). It allows you to reference the variable using just the class name, in this case (`HelloWorld.str`). When the variable belongs to the local scope, as in the method body, it cannot be declared as static because it is not a member of the class.

Comment: I know its invalid but why??

Comment: @mohit Why would it be valid ? how would you use it ?

Comment: `static` is used to access a variable without an instance, a local variable only exist in the scope of the method itself. So having a `static` local variable would not be accessible `HelloWorld.str` since this is not in the scope of the method.

Comment: @mohit `static` *roughly* means "for the class, not for the instance of the class". This definition does not apply to the method/local scope of the variable either way.

Answer (score 0):

A class can have static members, but  a method cannot have static variables in it.

You could move your `static String[] str={"one","two"};` above your declartion for `main(..)` which would move it into the class's scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are several kinds of variables:

- Member variables in a class—these are called *fields*.
- Variables in a method or block of code—these are called *local variables*.
- Variables in method declarations—these are called *parameters*.

*local variables* can not be `static`, only *fields* can be `static`. static fields don't belong to any instance, they belong to the class.

In this case, you can set `String[] str` as a class member:

```
static String[] str={"one","two"};

public static void main(String []args){
    // use str
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Static members are part of the class.. you cannot declare a static variable inside a method.

It should rather be like this

Class Helloworld{
static String [] a={"a","b"};

public static void main(String args){

}

Comment: This looks as if you copied my answer and then reworded it.