# Why we cannot use static keyword inside a method in java?

Tags: java, static, final

I tried to create static object and variable inside the method but i cannot.
This same operation is possible outside the method. Please help me anyone.

```
Class Sample()
{

}    
class Example
{
    void Mark()
    {
        static int i=100; //Error, only final is allowed
        Static Sample s=new Sample();// Error, only final is allowed 
        System.out.println(i);  
    }
}
public class StaticObject
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Example e=new Example();
        e.Mark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What would it mean to have a static local variable?

Comment: How would that work, exactly?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274375 (a better duplicate, IMO).

Comment: A side comment, but you really should learn to indent your code properly

Comment: Just FYI, C++ allows static variable in methods, so this question is not as ridiculous as the comments are making it seem. That it doesn't make sense in java is a different story, I assume the OP has a C++ background.

Comment: i just tried to use the composition inside the method with single memory address only.